# Does $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}])$ have a finite presentation?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-presentation

The [modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group) group $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ can be written as something that is nearly a free group on two elements:
$$ SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} = \left\{ S,T: S^2 =I; (ST)^3 = I\right\} $$
where $S: z \mapsto - \frac{1}{z}$ and $T : z \mapsto z + 1$ are the reciprocal and shift maps.  These can turn into many many things.

What happens if we adjoin $\sqrt{2}$ and look at the special linear group there? Do we still get that it is the free group on two elements?
$$ 
SL_2\big(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \big) = \left\{
\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)\in M_{2 \times 2}(\,\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \,): ad -bc=1  \right\}
$$

---

These are not [Bianchi groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bianchi_group) because I am asking about $\sqrt{2}$ instead of $\sqrt{-2}$.

On the bright side, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a one of a handful of [quadratic fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_field) that are **[Euclidean domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Norm-Euclidean_fields), (so they are "norm-Euclidean")**.  Therefore, solutions to $ad-bc = 1$ are not too hard to generate with $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^4$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}^4$.

Comment: $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathcal{O}_F)$ has (virtual) cohomological dimension $2r + 3s - 1$ where $F$ is a number field with signature $(r,s)$.

Comment: Yes, since it is an arithmetic group.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as every arithmetic group (as mentioned by Moishe Cohen). See Soulé's paper "An introduction to arithmetic groups", Theorem 6 p13, https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00001348/document

He refers to a 1963 paper by Armand Borel and Raghunathan's book "Discrete subgroups of Lie groups".

$\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}])$ is an irreducible, non-cocompact lattice, in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})^2$. Its behavior, in many respects, is closer to that of $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$ than to that of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$. In particular, finite presentation, using a retraction, is proved in a similar way. I guess there are also approaches in the spirit of algebraic K-theory.

Comment: yeah. you are using a sledgehammer to get this result but yes. conversely if I'm interested in an arithmetic group like $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}])$ is now a time to consider learning algebraic K-theory ?

Comment: Yes, I think it's a good motivation (although the case of $\mathbf{SL}_2$ is a bit degenerated for algebraic K-theory).